# Ruby - Change timezone globally

Tags: ruby, datetime, rubygems

I'm currently writing a program in Ruby in which I've to get the current time (from my machine). The problem in here is, that I'm two timezones ahead and just decrement the hours by 2.

GMT+2 - 2 = GMT+0

Now my question would be, if there's any smarter way in doing so?
I wasn't able to find anything.

Just to give another example from another language:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT+0');
```

It sets the default timezone to GMT+0, but I guess it's kinda self explanatory. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```rb
t = Time.now.getlocal('+00:00')
```

Comment: This doesn’t change the default time zone, does it? If this is the solution to your problem you should rephrase your question.

Comment: @Stefan it in fact does not, but it's way simpler than the way I used to have it in. If you've any other suggestions, feel free to answer :)